# Breaking large file into chunks and searching for duplicates using a common delimiter PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

We have software on our PC's which sends it's information to an FTP on our server on a weekly basis. The problem is it generates a new file each time, so i made a php script on the viewlogs page which will write all the logs into one large file, and then remove the unique files. And this works great, except there is a lot of junk in the file for which i don't care for, and also since it's every week, it generates a lot of duplicates which annoys the hell out of me. The actual relevant information has a common and useful format. Take the example below:

```
  ==================================================
  PCN               : <name>
  Web Browser       : <main browser>
  User Name         : <AD user>
  lastlogn          : <loginDate>
  WindowsUpdateStat : <importantOraboveUpdatesOutstanding>
  CompAssetTagNum   : <tag>
  ManufacturerNm    : <thierName>
  ==================================================

  ==================================================
  PCN               : <name>
  Web Browser       : <main browser>
  User Name         : <AD user>
  lastlogn          : <loginDate>
  WindowsUpdateStat : <importantOraboveUpdatesOutstanding>
  CompAssetTagNum   : <tag>
  ManufacturerNm    : <thierName>
  ==================================================
```

As you can see each useful section is delimited by an equal row of '=' charicters.
Currently my code is this:

```
  if (file_exists($recovery)){  
                $ncont= file_get_contents($fileToRead);
                $ocont= file_get_contents($recovery);
                $ocont .= $ncont;
                file_put_contents($recovery, $ocont);
                echo "WriterRecoveryRan";
                unlink($fileToRead);
            }
```

I have read that you can use explode/implode to search through the array which would be $ocont for the delimiter and split the file into chunks like that?

Is it possible i can during the reading process ONLY read data that has the equals around it like displayed above, and then possibly take a hash of each chunk and put that into an array, check that array for duplicate hashes, and remove the corresponding duplication?

I apologise if this question seems very broad. If it is unacceptably so, i shall edit.

Thanks for any help/pointers/ideas.

Comment: You have not shown any code attempts at where you are trying to extract meaningful data from the concatenated file data.  What problem are you having in doing this?

Comment: explode/implode don't "Search". they just convert a string into an array and back using a specified delimiter.

Comment: I have not shown any code, because i am unsure quite how to go about this.